# mysql error on OrthoMCL

Tags: php, mysql

While working with `OrthoMCL` I get to a part in which I have to upload my data in MySQL and then the program should make pairs of my data which are basically protein sequences.
While running the command `orthomclPairs` I get the following error

`DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Table 'BestQueryTaxonScore' already exists at /home/sebastian/Downloads/OrthoMCL_v_2.0/orthomclSoftware-v2.0.9/bin/orthomclPairs line 709, <F> line 14`.

To me it seems my database is full of information from a previous analysis and some tables may have the same names so a good solution would be reset the database .

AM I right? How can I solve this issue?

I appreciate your help and I' m sorry if something I say does not make sense but I am very new to "computers".

Answer (score 1):

So the answer to my question is this:

Drop the database everytime you've ran the program (i.e. everytime you have uploaded the parsed BLAST search).

The database can be droped as follows:

mysql -u user -p DATABASE NAME (login with privileges)

Then this

drop database YOUR_DATABASE   (this will delete all the tables for this database)

Then this

create database YOUR_DATABASE; (adds back the database namespace)

then just installschema outside MySQL

I hope it' s helpful for other working with MyOrthomcl.

Answer (score 0):

Without any familiarity with this OrthoMCL software, it's perfectly obvious from the error message that the script attempted to create a table that was already present.

If you're setting up to work on a new problem, perhaps there's a way to create a new database. In MySQL parlance, a new database will let you create tables with the same name in it.

Or, as you say, you might "reset" your existing database. But that's OrthoMCL parlance, not MySQL parlance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How do I reset my newly created database inside mysql?

Comment: Does the OrthoMCL documentation say anything about resetting, or starting a new problem?  If you have access to a MySQL client you could drop and recreate the database. But I'm reluctant to give you a recipe for that because it's a very destructive operation and might foul up your OrthoMCL operation beyond recovery. This question is best asked in a support forum for that package.

Comment: Hi thank you again. It seems that you have to "drop" your database every time you run your analysis so your guess was right. Basically because the database is populated with the information from a previous run and it keeps stored and it is accumulative as far as I understand. It can also be done by "droping" the tables created during the analysis but I just tried the former not the latter. Anyway, once it' s worked for my 4 runs I will post it as an answer to my question. I really appreaciate your help. Sorry for any mistakes.